# How to split up an Eloquent model query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to break up an Eloquent query like this

```
$query = new Product;

if (!empty($req->query['id'])) {
    $query->where('id', '=', '1');
}

$products = $query->get();
```

The result above gives me all products in the database. This however, does in fact work.

```
$products = Product::where('id', '=', '1')->get();
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel 4 you need to append your query parameters to your query variable. In Laravel 3, it would work like you're doing.

This is what you need to do (I'm unsure if it will work with `new Product` tho):

```
$query = new Product;

if (!empty($req->query['id'])) {
    $query = $query->where('id', '=', '1');
}

$products = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make sense. If you make a `new Product` - then it will never have an ID associated with it - so your `if (!empty($req->query['id']))` will always be false.

Are you just trying to get a specific product idea?

```
$products = Product::find(1);
```

is the same as

```
$products = Product::where('id', '=', '1')->get();
```