# Laravel eloquent split query in multiple steps

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, split, eloquent

I think the title is quite confusing, I will try to explain this as good as possible. Lets say I have quite a big query for searching posts, something like this:

```
$posts = Post::select('...')
           ->leftJoin('...')
           ->leftJoin('...')
           ->where('...')
           ->orWhere('...')
           ->orderBy('...')
           ->orderBy('...')
           ->groupBy('...')
           ->with('...')
           ->paginate(8);
```

How can I split this query? For example:

```
$posts = Post::select('...')
           ->leftJoin('...')
           ->leftJoin('...')

$posts->where('...')
      ->orWhere('...');

$posts->orderBy('...')
      ->orderBy('...')
      ->groupBy('...');

$posts->with('...')
      ->paginate(8);
```

Im using Laravel 4.2 and I tried several things (including [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852769/how-to-split-up-an-eloquent-model-query)), but I can't get it to work. I need this for searching and filtering posts.

Comment: Can you post the actual code you are using? What errors did you get?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Start by creating a new instance of your model and seting it to a variable, build your query using that variable, and then end with a `get()`:

```
$posts = new Post;
$posts = $posts->where('...');
$posts = $posts->orWhere('...');
$posts = $posts->orderBy('...');
...
$posts = $posts->get();
```

Rather than doing all this chaining, though, you can probably streamline things quite a bit by using query scopes and some well-structured relation methods.

Comment: Works great, I tried `$posts->where('...')` right after, the trick was to use `$posts = $posts->where('...')'. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any problem while we need the ordered result in one variable $postsOrdered & un-ordered result in $posts
posts = new Post;
$posts = $posts->where('...');
$posts = $posts->orWhere('...');
$postsOrdered = $posts->orderBy('...');
...
$posts = $posts->get();
The $posts result is affected by the upper one i.e the $posts get ordered.
How can i overcome this.